# Weird error when trying to take a snapshot of a uiview using UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I'm getting the following error when I call this extension:

```
extension UIView {
    
    /// Create image snapshot of view.
    func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect ?? bounds).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> vImageConvert_AnyToAny - failed width = 0 height = 1 dst component =
> 16bit float dstLayout = ByteOrder16Little dstBytesPerRow = 0 src
> component = 16bit integer srcLayout = ByteOrder16Little srcBytesPerRow
> = 0

Any ideas why this would be the case?  Wondering if a color space issue... works fine on simulator, breaks on physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for others that need something similar:

```
extension UIView {
    
    /// Create image snapshot of view.
    func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage {
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect!)
                return renderer.image { (context) in
                    self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
                }
    }
}
```